# Unexpected Automatic Scroll to Top in Android Paging 3 Recycler View After Loading Next Page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination, algolia

I'm currently integrating the `Paging 3` library into my Android application, utilizing a `RecyclerView` to display data. While the basic implementation is in place, I'm encountering an unexpected behavior related to `scrolling` after loading the next page of data. Specifically, the `RecyclerView` is automatically scrolling to the top position after loading new data, which is not the intended behavior.

The setup involves using the `PagingDataAdapter` along with the `RecyclerView` as per `Paging 3's guidelines`. `Pagination` is working correctly, but the `automatic scroll` to the top after fetching and loading subsequent pages is proving to be problematic. The goal is to have users continue viewing their current position without being abruptly taken to the top of the list whenever new data is loaded.

**The relevant portion of my code resembles the following:**

```
mSSSPagination(
            searcher = productSearcher,
            pagingConfig = PagingConfig(pageSize = 20, enablePlaceholders = false),
            transformer = {
                it.deserialize(ProductAlgolia.serializer())
            }
        )


paginator?.liveData?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { pagingData ->
        plpAdapter?.submitData(lifecycle, pagingData)
    }
```

**Paging Source Code Snippet**

```
class SSSSearcherPagingSource<T : Any>(
private val searcher: SearcherForHits<out SearchParameters>,
private val transformer: (ResponseSearch.Hit) -> T
) : PagingSource<Int, T>() {

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, T>): Int {
    return 0 // on refresh (for new query), start from the first page (number zero)
}

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, T> {
    return try {
        val pageNumber = params.key ?: 0
        searcher.query.page = pageNumber
        searcher.query.hitsPerPage = 20

        val response = search() ?: return emptyPage()
        val data = response.hits.map(transformer)
        val nextKey = if (pageNumber < response.nbPages) pageNumber + 1 else null
        LoadResult.Page(
            data = data,
            prevKey = null, // no paging backward
            nextKey = nextKey
        )
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.w("Paging search operation failed", exception)
        LoadResult.Error(exception)
    }
}
```

**Pagination Issue Video**

[Pagination Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KUikMJW630OCmRwkPS1-zCigLhLYsnnN/view?usp=sharing)

**Update 1**

**Paginator Code**

```
public fun <T : Any> Paginator(
    searcher: SearcherForHits<out SearchParameters>,
    pagingConfig: PagingConfig = PagingConfig(pageSize = 10),
    transformer: (ResponseSearch.Hit) -> T
): Paginator<T> = SearcherPaginator(
    pagingConfig = pagingConfig,
    pagingSourceFactory = { SearcherPagingSource(searcher, transformer) }
)

/**
 * A cold Flow of [PagingData], emits new instances of [PagingData] once they become invalidated.
 */
public val <T : Any> Paginator<T>.flow: Flow<PagingData<T>> get() = pager.flow

/**
 * A LiveData of [PagingData], which mirrors the stream provided by [flow], but exposes it as a LiveData.
 */
public val <T : Any> Paginator<T>.liveData: LiveData<PagingData<T>> get() = pager.liveData
```

**Diff Util Code Snippet**

```
object ProductDiffUtil : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ProductAlgolia>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ProductAlgolia, newItem: ProductAlgolia): Boolean {
            return oldItem.objectID == newItem.objectID
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ProductAlgolia, newItem: ProductAlgolia): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**

**Load State Collection Snippet**

```
private fun setLoadingStates() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        plpAdapter?.loadStateFlow?.collectLatest { loadStates ->
            //Log.d("loadState", loadStates.toString())
            Log.d("productList", plpAdapter?.getProductAlgoliaList().toString())
            when (loadStates.refresh) {

                !is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        val productList = plpAdapter?.getProductList() ?: arrayListOf()
                        if (productList.isNotEmpty()) {
                            if (!isFromSearch) {
                                createCategoryTabs(productList, selectedCategoryId)
                            }
                            trackAlgoliaPLPView()
                            initMostUsedFilter()
                            trackMoengagePLPViewEvent(productList = productList)
                        } else {
                           noDataFound()
                        }

                        if (isFromSearch) {
                            val suggestion =
                                algoliaViewModel.suggestions.value?.peekContent()?.second
                            val query = algoliaViewModel.suggestions.value?.peekContent()?.first

                            trackMoEngageSearchEvent(
                                selectedQuery = suggestion?.query,
                                searchText = query,
                                productList.isEmpty()
                            )
                        }


                    hideShimmer()
                }

                is LoadState.Error -> {
                    hideShimmer()
                }

                else -> {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView**

```
<com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/plpRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_55dp"
                android:splitMotionEvents="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:shimmer_demo_layout="@layout/plp_placeholder"
                app:shimmer_demo_layout_manager_type="grid"
                app:shimmer_demo_shimmer_color="#21ffffff"
                tools:visibility="invisible" />
```

Note: I have observed that while loading the next page Paging adapter position start from 0

**For example**

> Page 0 -> 20 products
>
> page 1 -> loading next 20 products -> position start from 0 **(Unexpected)**

Comment: Are you able to share you code? There are a number of things that could be happening, but otherwise I would also share how you are creating `paginator`, where exactly you are observing `LiveData<PagingData>` from, what your `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` looks like and I would double check you are never invalidating or refreshing the list, as your getRefreshKey() just returns 0.

Comment: @dlam added the required code please have a look

Comment: So far, the code you have here doesn't seem like it should cause your list to jump up, couple other things to check:

1. Collect from `PagingDataAdapter.loadStateFlow` and log the items from `PagingDataAdapter.snapshot()` to ensure it matches what you're expecting

2. Can you share when / where Paginator is instantiated from, how you're passing it to UI and where you are calling `paginator?.liveData?.observe` from?

3. Last thing is a bit more about your UI; aside from lifecycle stuff above what does your layout containing your RV powered by Paging look like?

Comment: Fwiw - my guess at the moment is you are unexpectedly re-creating the Pager or resetting it on some UI update. This would make it reset the scroll position without `initialLoadKey` or `.cachedIn()` or `.getRefreshKey()` implemented properly as you have here.

Comment: @dlam `PagingDataAdapter.snapshot()` gives me the records from the top (Unexpected), I have shared the `load state collection` code please have a look Furthermore, `pagination` is initiated in `OnCreate` and finally I have added the `recyclerview` `XML` as well

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, but glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, I am using one shimmer library which is causing the issue the problem is that when I am hiding the shimmer one method which is getting called causing the issue

```
binding.plpRecyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter()
```

This method is replacing the shimmer adapter with the actual adapter

**Library Code Snippet**

```
public void hideShimmerAdapter() {
    mCanScroll = true;
    setLayoutManager(mActualLayoutManager);
    setAdapter(mActualAdapter);
}

public void setLayoutManager(LayoutManager manager) {
    if (manager == null) {
        mActualLayoutManager = null;
    } else if (manager != mShimmerLayoutManager) {
        mActualLayoutManager = manager;
    }

    super.setLayoutManager(manager);
}
```

I removed that library and manage shimmer by my own instead of using library